# When connecting to a backend server using Axios I'll get the following error "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios, web-development-server

So I'm making a Web Application app using React. so I have created a login/register function to allow users to either signup or login to their account. I have used an express server to send http requests to MYSQL database, I also created two endpoints to either '/register' or '/login'. For my frontend I have connected the app to those endpoints using Axios to post users data into the database. my application only works when both server and client files are running on the same port, which could be disrupted when you refresh the page, however, the app would totally work if you don't refresh the page. so my question is that how can I get those http requests and post them into my database without having my frontend and backend running on the same port. Thx:)

Frontend:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';


function Login2() {
    //Saving the values in the form variable
    const [form, setForm] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });
    //mode determines whether the form should disply login or register
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('login');
    //message is used to disply any form of error to the user
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    //it updates the users values in case a change has been made 
    //used a spread operator to update the form by targeting .name and .value 
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({
            ...form,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    //it is used when the form is submitted, sends message to the backend to either login or register
    //if successful/denied  response is saved in message
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (mode === 'login') {
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/login', form)
                .then((response) => {
                    setMessage(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setMessage(error.message);
                });
        } else {
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register', form)
                .then((response) => {
                    setMessage(response.data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setMessage(error.message);
                });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={form.username}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {mode === 'register' && (
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value={form.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                )}
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={form.password}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button type="submit">
                    {mode === 'login' ? 'Login' : 'Register'}
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => setMode(mode === 'login' ? 'register' : 'login')}>
                    Switch to {mode === 'login' ? 'Register' : 'Login'}
                </button>
            </form>
            {message && <p>{message}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login2;
```

Backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "??",
    user: "??",
    password: "??",
    database: "??",
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const reg = `INSERT INTO userTable (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)`;
    connection.query(reg, [username, email, password], (error) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send('User registered successfully');
    });
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const log = `SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`;
    connection.query(log, [username, password], (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (!results.length) {
            return res.send('Username or password is incorrect');
        }
        res.send('Login successful');
    });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making post request to a wrong port. Your server is running on 4000 and your are making axios post request on port 3000. Do the following changes in your react code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/login', form)
```

and

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/register', form)
```

But since you are requesting to the server from a different port, other than on what its running (here in your project its 4000) you will get a CORS error. For that you need to install `cors` package and do the necessary configuration depending on your project.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot Roshan, it completely works after setting up cors:)